# How to setup babel-standalone in my none node js environment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to use es6's import, require and export in my web app using codeigniter.
i found babel-standalone but it's not working.[screenshot of embed js files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juub6.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on 'it's not working'. Give details, like specific error messages.

Comment: import, require and export is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the added detail that

> import, require and export is undefined

Here's the problem: that's not what Babel does. Babel transpiles code: it turns one file of ES6 code into a file that contains ES5 code that does the same thing. It does *not* combine source code files that use `require` or `import` into bundles.

You're looking for browserify or Webpack to do that - they are bundlers, tools that let you use require, import, and export to organize code. You'll need to use one of them to accomplish your goal - Babel alone will not do what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you sir.. yeah! i figured that out lately. but thanks anyway :)